# ¿Como aplicar el promedio por filas en un dataframe con valores NaN incluidos?

Tags: python

Hola tengo el siguiente dataframe y deseo calcular el promedio de los valores que están junto a 2007002, 2007005, 2007006 y asi consecutivamente, estos caluclos del promedio los quiero en forma de iteración para la columna "alt" o sea en esta columna primero en la fila 0, luego en la fila 1 y asi consecutivamente, el detalle es que NaN esta en la data y mean() no lo podría calcular si esta presente, y el archivo en la columna "alt" tiene 1200 filas (el archivos original es muy largo) ¿como podría iterar en la columna "alt" pero incluyendo los promedios en las fila con los datos NaN?

Mi archivo es:

```
    alt evnt    orbit   date    ktemp
    0   0      27447    2007002 NaN
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 NaN
        3      27491    2007005 NaN
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 NaN
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 NaN
        8      27550    2007009 NaN
        9      27550    2007009 NaN
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 NaN
       13      27594    2007012 NaN
       14      27594    2007012 NaN
   1    0      27447    2007002 101.2
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 105.2
        3      27491    2007005 104.2
        4      27491    2007005 100.1
        5      27506    2007006 98.5
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 99.2
        8      27550    2007009 102.1
        9      27550    2007009 97.5
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 105.2
       13      27594    2007012 100.1
       14      27594    2007012 95.2
   2    0      27447    2007002 99.3
        1      27447    2007002 100.5
        2      27491    2007005 98.4
        3      27491    2007005 99.5
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 94.5
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 100.3
        8      27550    2007009 101.5
        9      27550    2007009 102.4
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 95.4
       12      27594    2007012 94.3
       13      27594    2007012 93.2
       14      27594    2007012 100.2
  3     0      27447    2007002 NaN
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 NaN
        3      27491    2007005 NaN
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 NaN
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 NaN
        8      27550    2007009 NaN
        9      27550    2007009 NaN
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 NaN
       13      27594    2007012 NaN
       14      27594    2007012 NaN
   4    0      27447    2007002 NaN
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 NaN
        3      27491    2007005 NaN
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 NaN
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 NaN
        8      27550    2007009 NaN
        9      27550    2007009 NaN
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 NaN
       13      27594    2007012 NaN
       14      27594    2007012 NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio debería funcionar también aunque haya NaN en la columna. El método `.mean()` de pandas tiene un parámetro opcional `skipna` que tiene por defecto al valor `True`. Esto implica que se salta las filas en las que el valor sea NaN.

Por tanto, si un grupo tuviera por ejemplo los valores 10, 20, y el resto NaN, el resultado sería 15 (promedio entre 10 y 20). Si todos los elementos a promediar son NaN, el resultado obviamente será NaN, pues no está definido.

Por tanto lo que quieres se lograría así:

```
df.groupby(["alt", "date"]).ktemp.mean()
```

Aplicando esto a los datos que proporcionas de ejemplo sale:

```
alt  date   
0    2007002           NaN
     2007005           NaN
     2007006           NaN
     2007009           NaN
     2007012           NaN
1    2007002    101.200000
     2007005    103.166667
     2007006     98.850000
     2007009     99.800000
     2007012    100.166667
2    2007002     99.900000
     2007005     98.950000
     2007006     97.400000
     2007009     99.766667
     2007012     95.900000
3    2007002           NaN
     2007005           NaN
     2007006           NaN
     2007009           NaN
     2007012           NaN
4    2007002           NaN
     2007005           NaN
     2007006           NaN
     2007009           NaN
     2007012           NaN
```

Comment: cuando le doy un print(df.groupby(["alt", "date"]) me imprime: <pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000020B8BD19B08>

Comment: Si, porque eso simplemente hace una agrupación. Es necesario que después apliques una función agregadora sobre la agrupación como por ejemplo `.mean()`, tal como hice en la respuesta. Hay otras funciones agrupadoras (quedarse con el máximo, el mínimo, la suma total, etc.) pero tú preguntabas por el promedio.

Comment: me imprime esto:                                                                          
     alt  date
    0    2007002.0      NaN
    1      100.5           NaN
          2007002.0    101.2
    2    98.4           NaN
          105.2          NaN
        2007002.0     99.3
    3    99.5           NaN
         104.2          NaN
    4    100.1          NaN
    5    98.5           NaN
    7    99.2           NaN
    8    102.1          NaN
    9    97.5           NaN
  12   105.2          NaN
  13   100.1          NaN
  14   95.2           NaN

Comment: no se aprecia bien en el comentario

Comment: Pero no entiendo qué me quieres decir. ¿No te sale lo que esperas? ¿En qué se separa lo que obtienes de lo que esperas? Como ves en mi ejemplo a mi sí parece haberme funcionado. ¿Es tu dataframe igual al del ejemplo? Igual era conveniente que editaras la pregunta (o hicieras otra) para proporcionar un ejemplo de un caso en el que no te sale lo que esperabas.

Comment: voy a escribir otra pregunta especificando el problema

Comment: ya esta la pregunta hecha en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401004/problemas-con-groupby-en-python