# Problemas con groupby en python

Tags: python

Hola estoy tratando de calcular el promedio de un grupo de filas usando groupby, pero mi resultado no es el correcto.

Mi archivo txt es el siguiente:

```
     alt evnt    orbit   date    ktemp
    0   0      27447    2007002 NaN
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 NaN
        3      27491    2007005 NaN
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 NaN
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 NaN
        8      27550    2007009 NaN
        9      27550    2007009 NaN
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 NaN
       13      27594    2007012 NaN
       14      27594    2007012 NaN
   1    0      27447    2007002 101.2
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 105.2
        3      27491    2007005 104.2
        4      27491    2007005 100.1
        5      27506    2007006 98.5
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 99.2
        8      27550    2007009 102.1
        9      27550    2007009 97.5
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 105.2
       13      27594    2007012 100.1
       14      27594    2007012 95.2
   2    0      27447    2007002 99.3
        1      27447    2007002 100.5
        2      27491    2007005 98.4
        3      27491    2007005 99.5
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 94.5
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 100.3
        8      27550    2007009 101.5
        9      27550    2007009 102.4
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 95.4
       12      27594    2007012 94.3
       13      27594    2007012 93.2
       14      27594    2007012 100.2
  3     0      27447    2007002 NaN
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 NaN
        3      27491    2007005 NaN
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 NaN
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 NaN
        8      27550    2007009 NaN
        9      27550    2007009 NaN
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 NaN
       13      27594    2007012 NaN
       14      27594    2007012 NaN
   4    0      27447    2007002 NaN
        1      27447    2007002 NaN
        2      27491    2007005 NaN
        3      27491    2007005 NaN
        4      27491    2007005 NaN
        5      27506    2007006 NaN
        6      27506    2007006 NaN
        7      27506    2007006 NaN
        8      27550    2007009 NaN
        9      27550    2007009 NaN
       10      27550    2007009 NaN
       11      27550    2007009 NaN
       12      27594    2007012 NaN
       13      27594    2007012 NaN
       14      27594    2007012 NaN
```

Mi código es:

```
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.read_csv('Mi_archivo.txt', header = 0, delim_whitespace = True)

pd.set_option("display.max_rows",df.shape[0]+1)

print(df.groupby(["alt", "date"]).ktemp.mean())
```

El resultado esta en la url: [¿Como aplicar el promedio por filas en un dataframe con valores NaN incluidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400971/como-aplicar-el-promedio-por-filas-en-un-dataframe-con-valores-nan-incluidos)

el cual deberia ser:

```
alt  date   
0    2007002           NaN
     2007005           NaN
     2007006           NaN
     2007009           NaN
     2007012           NaN
1    2007002    101.200000
     2007005    103.166667
     2007006     98.850000
     2007009     99.800000
     2007012    100.166667
2    2007002     99.900000
     2007005     98.950000
     2007006     97.400000
     2007009     99.766667
     2007012     95.900000
3    2007002           NaN
     2007005           NaN
     2007006           NaN
     2007009           NaN
     2007012           NaN
4    2007002           NaN
     2007005           NaN
     2007006           NaN
     2007009           NaN
     2007012           NaN
```

sin embargo mi programa me imprime:

```
alt  date
0    2007002.0      NaN
1    100.5          NaN
     2007002.0    101.2
2    98.4           NaN
     105.2          NaN
     2007002.0     99.3
3    99.5           NaN
     104.2          NaN
     2007002.0      NaN
4    100.1          NaN
     2007002.0      NaN
5    94.5           NaN
     98.5           NaN
7    99.2           NaN
     100.3          NaN
8    101.5          NaN
     102.1          NaN
9    97.5           NaN
     102.4          NaN
11   95.4           NaN
12   94.3           NaN
     105.2          NaN
13   93.2           NaN
     100.1          NaN
14   95.2           NaN
     100.2          NaN
Name: ktemp, dtype: float64
```

¿Cual podria ser el problema mi código?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue formulada 3 veces.

Comment: @marmurar tengo ese problema con la impresión no se que pueda ser

Comment: cual podria ser la solución? por que los archivos descargados tienen esa estructura.

Comment: @abulafia y que código usaste para que en la anterior pregunta te resultara los promedios con esa estructura, esa es mi duda

Comment: podria repetirse en "alt" por ejejmplo en las columnas vacias del grupo donde 0 con ceros, 1 con 1 y asi sucesivamente?

Comment: Si pudieras hacer eso antes de exportar a csv sería la solución más simple, pues de ahí ya lo leería pandas bien. Si estás preguntando si se puede hacer eso desde pandas, la respuesta es que no, porque antes necesitamos leerlo y ya lo está leyendo mal. Pero se puede pre-procesar ese fichero con python para añadirle lo que falta. Es lo que estoy escribiendo ahora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es el `groupby()` ni el cálculo de la media, sino la lectura del fichero. O mejor dicho, el formato del fichero.

Éste no es correcto ya que en la columna "alt" solo tiene valor en la primera fila, y en las múltiplo de 16. En las demás esa columna no tiene nada, por lo que el `read_csv()` "se confunde" y asigna a la columna "alt" lo que está en la columna "evnt", y a ésta lo que hay en "orbit", etc y así todo queda descolocado en `df` y por eso no salen los valores esperados.

Para que la lectura funcione correctamente, todas las filas deberían tener un valor en "alt" que sea igual al último "alt" leido (es decir, las primeras 16 filas tendrían "alt" 0, las 16 siguientes tendrían "alt" 1, y así sucesivamente).

Si no hay posibilidad de obtener los archivos en un formato correcto, podrían procesarse de la forma siguiente. Iterando por las líneas del fichero, para cada línea:

- Rompemos la línea con un `.split()`. Si se trata de la primera línea, esos serán los nombres de las columnas.
- Si es cualquier otra línea, y tiene el mismo número de elementos que el número de columnas, es que esa línea está bien y entonces la dejamos pasar tal cual, y tomamos nota del primer trozo, que será el valor de "alt"
- Si no tiene el número de elementos esperado, es que le falta "alt", y entonces le ponemos por delante el valor de "alt" que teníamos guardado de iteraciones anteriores.

En código:

```
filas = []
for n, linea in enumerate(open('Mi_archivo.txt')):
  trozos = linea.split()
  if n==0:
    columnas = trozos
    filas.append(linea)
    continue
  if len(trozos) == len(columnas):
    alt = trozos[0]
    filas.append(linea)
  else:
    filas.append(alt + " " + linea)

arreglado = "".join(filas)
```

Al terminar ese bucle, `arreglado` contendrá una larga cadena con los contenidos del fichero .csv en el formato "bueno" en el que todas las filas tienen un valor para el campo "alt".

Para no tener que guardar esa cadena a fichero, podemos usar `io.StringIO()` que permite usar los contenidos de una cadena como si fuesen un fichero, para pasárselos directamente a pandas:

```
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(arreglado), header = 0, delim_whitespace = True)
```

El resultado en `df` es ahora:

```
    alt  evnt  orbit     date  ktemp
0     0     0  27447  2007002    NaN
1     0     1  27447  2007002    NaN
2     0     2  27491  2007005    NaN
3     0     3  27491  2007005    NaN
4     0     4  27491  2007005    NaN
..  ...   ...    ...      ...    ...
70    4    10  27550  2007009    NaN
71    4    11  27550  2007009    NaN
72    4    12  27594  2007012    NaN
73    4    13  27594  2007012    NaN
74    4    14  27594  2007012    NaN

[75 rows x 5 columns]
```

Que ya tiene la estructura correcta para aplicarle la operación:

```
df.groupby(["alt", "date"]).ktemp.mean()
```